# Hide button when last child element of parent is visible

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML code:

```
<div id="work-field">
  <div class="inline">Field inline1</div>
  <div class="inline">Field inline2</div>
  <div class="inline">Field inline3</div>
  <div class="inline">Field inline4</div>
  <div class="inline">Field inline5</div>
  <div class="inline">...</div>
</div>

<div id="work-area">
  <div class="inline">Area inline 1</div>
  <div class="inline">Area inline 2</div>
  <div class="inline">Area inline 3</div>
  <div class="inline">Area inline 4</div>
  <div class="inline">Area inline 5</div>
  <div class="inline">...</div>
</div>
```

And using this javascript code:

```
$('#work-area, #work-field').addClass('js-inline');
var nextbutton = '<a href="#" class="next">Next</a>';
$(nextbutton).insertAfter('.js-inline > div.inline:last-child');
$('.js-inline').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $(this).children('.inline:not(:first-child)').css('display', 'none');
});

$('.next').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $(this).click(function(e) {
        var $this = $(this);
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().find('.inline:visible').next().show();
    })
});
```

The above JS code will:

- Add ".js-inline" class to the 2 parent elements (work-field, work-area).
- Add "Next" button after the last ".inline" in each ".js-inline" div.
- Hide every ".inline" element, except for first element in each div.
- Function to show the next (hidden) .inline in the current .js-inline parent when clicked on "Next" link.

Now the problem is that when the last .inline element is shown, i want the "Next" button to disappear, i tried this code but it didn't work.

```
if ( $('.js-inline').find('.inner:visible').next().next().length == 0 ) {
   $('.next').hide();
}
```

The above line has been inserted after this line:

```
$(this).parent().find('.inline:visible').next().show();
```

My question: What is the required IF statement to make the functionality needed to work, and where it should be?

Comment: Why are you assigning `$(this)` to a variable, then not use it?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I'm beginner in JS/Jquery, i searched stackoverflow to get what i needed for this code to work, and it was in one of the examples, since it's not necessary/unused i think i should remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `is(':visible')` to check whether an element is visible so

```js
$('#work-area, #work-field').addClass('js-inline');
var nextbutton = '<a href="#" class="next">Next</a>';
$(nextbutton).insertAfter('.js-inline > div.inline:last-child');
$('.js-inline').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $(this).children('.inline:not(:first-child)').css('display', 'none');
});

$('.next').click(function(e) {
  var $this = $(this);
  e.preventDefault();
  $this.parent().find('.inline:visible').last().next().show();
  $this.toggle(!$this.parent().find('.inline').last().is(':visible'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="work-field">
  <div class="inline">Field inline1</div>
  <div class="inline">Field inline2</div>
  <div class="inline">Field inline3</div>
  <div class="inline">Field inline4</div>
  <div class="inline">Field inline5</div>
  <div class="inline">...</div>
</div>

<div id="work-area">
  <div class="inline">Area inline 1</div>
  <div class="inline">Area inline 2</div>
  <div class="inline">Area inline 3</div>
  <div class="inline">Area inline 4</div>
  <div class="inline">Area inline 5</div>
  <div class="inline">...</div>
</div>
```